# How do I save a retrieve specific data from a csv file without headers in java?

Tags: java, csv, parsing

I am writing an application which needs to load a large csv file that is pure data and doesn't contain any headers.

I am using a fastCSV library to parse the file, however the data needs to be stored and specific fields need to be retrieved. Since the entire data is not necessary I am skipping every third line. 
Is there a way to set the headers after the file has been parsed and save it in a data structure such as an ArrayList?

Here is the function which loads the file:

```
public void fastCsv(String filePath) { 
    File file = new File(filePath);
    CsvReader csvReader = new CsvReader();
    int linecounter = 1;

    try (CsvParser csvParser = csvReader.parse(file, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
        CsvRow row;
        while ((row = csvParser.nextRow()) != null) {
            if ((linecounter % 3) > 0 ) {
            // System.out.println("Read line: " + row);
            //System.out.println("First column of line: " + row.getField(0));
            System.out.println(row);

            }
        linecounter ++;
        }
        System.out.println("Execution Time in ms: " + elapsedTime);
        csvParser.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[univocity-parsers](https://www.univocity.com/pages/univocity_parsers_tutorial) supports field selection and can do this very easily. It's also faster than the library you are using.

Here's how you can use it to select columns of interest:

#### Input

```
    String input = "X, X2, Symbol, Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume\n" +
            " 5, 9, AAPL, 01-Jan-2015, 110.38, 110.38, 110.38, 110.38, 0\n" +
            " 2710, 289,  AAPL, 01-Jan-2015, 110.38, 110.38, 110.38, 110.38, 0\n" +
            " 5415, 6500, AAPL, 02-Jan-2015, 111.39, 111.44, 107.35, 109.33, 53204600";
```

#### Configure

```
    CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings(); //many options here, check the tutorial
    settings.setHeaderExtractionEnabled(true); //tells the parser to use the first row as the header row
    settings.selectFields("X", "X2"); //selects the fields
```

#### Parse and print results

```
    CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);
    for(String[] row : parser.iterate(new StringReader(input))){
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
    }
}
```

#### Output

```
[5, 9]
[2710, 289]
[5415, 6500]
```

On the field selection, you can use any sequence of fields, and have rows with different column sizes, and the parser will handle this just fine. No need to write complex logic to handle that.

The process the `File` in your code, change the example above to do this:

```
    for(String[] row : parser.iterate(new File(filePath))){
         ... //your logic goes here.
    }
```

If you want a more usable record (with typed values), use this instead:

```
    for(Record record : parser.iterateRecords(new File(filePath))){
         ... //your logic goes here.
    }
```

#### Speeding up

The fastest way of processing the file is through a `RowProcessor`. That's a callback that received the rows parsed from the input:

```
settings.setProcessor(new AbstractRowProcessor() {
    @Override
    public void rowProcessed(String[] row, ParsingContext context) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
        context.skipLines(3); //use the context object to control the parser
    }
});

CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);
//`parse` doesn't return anything. Rows go to the `rowProcessed` method.
parser.parse(new StringReader(input));
```

You should be able to parse very large files pretty quickly. If things are slowing down look in your code (avoid adding values to lists or collections in memory, or at least pre-allocate the collections to a good size, and give the JVM a large amount of memory to work with using Xms and Xmx flags).

Right now this parser is the fastest you can find. I made this [performance comparison](https://github.com/uniVocity/csv-parsers-comparison) a while ago you can use for reference.

Hope this helps

Disclosure: I am the author of this library. It's open-source and free (Apache V2.0 license)

Comment: This seems like a mure more elegant way of doing it. Is there a way to only select a sample of the data from the actual file? For instance, configuring the setting to  only read every 300th line of the file?

Comment: I have just tried the implementation and the only setting that had to be tweaked was the MaxColumn which was set to 512 by default. Although faster, the file did that a while to parse. I would like to add that I am working with large files (10GB+) and speed is of upmost importance. Are there any ways to increase the speed at which the file is processed? Thank you.

Comment: 10GB should be parsed in around 12 to 20 seconds. Try just running the parser without doing anything with the values first to establish a baseline and identify where the slowness is coming from. I've updated my answer with a `speeding up` section with other suggestions. Hope this helps.

Comment: In the Speeding Up section of the answer, I'm not sure if I'm correct but shouldn't it be parser.parse(new File(input)) instead? I tried it with StringReader and it just printed out the actual string which contained the path to the file. I have just ran the parser (with the RowProcessor) and the file still takes a considerable amount of time to process. Not entirely sure what is causing this.

Comment: @Pavlacc yes use the file. I just gave an example. Avoid printing the row to the output too. How much time is it taking?

Comment: Edit: The 11GB* file took 16 minutes to process. I have tried it with a different file which is ~4GB and halfway through it throws an ArrayOutOfBounds error at column 512 so i changed the MaxColumn once again. This file took around 9 minutes to process. Logically speaking the 10GB file should throw the same error as the 4GB file around column 513 with default settings.

Comment: You are either using some very limited hardware or there's something in your code that is making things that slow. I just parsed a 31GB file and it took less than 2 minutes.

Comment: The flaw was in fact within the code, it's fully functional now and the files are processed rapidly. I wanted to ask one more question, I have tried to load a data sample by using context.skipLines(); however all that did was return a single row of data. Is there another method of only processing a sample of the data instead of the entire file which would also improve execution time? Much appreciated.

Comment: Try `settings.setNumberOfRecordsToRead(10);`

Comment: Thank you so much for your input. This has really helped! Once last question I'd like to ask is related to column selection described above. More specifically whether the library offers a means of adding custom headers since the file I'm using doesn't contain any and if there's a way of storing the processed data in a data structure, e.g. ArrayList so that the features can be extracted. The settings have been tweaked to enable header extraction however the implementation of a csv writer within the parser isn't clear.

Comment: Try `parser.getContext().headers`, then when for writing create a `CsvWriter` and use `settings.setHeaders`. You can set the headers manually on the parser settings too. That takes precedence over what was found in the input (`context.headers` returns the acitve headers you set manually and can select and `context.parsedHeaders` returns what was parsed from the file)

Comment: I've implemented both `setNumbersOfRecordsToRead(10)` as well as `setNumberOfRowsToSkip(10)` however when the Skip method is executed there's a problem which states that the end of input is reached regardless of what value is used as the parameter. "Unable to skip n lines from line 0", I tried looking for a solution but nothing came across. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: That's how the parser behaves.  The next version wont throw when you call skip. You probably don't need that if you are using `setNumberOfRecordsToRead` anyway

Answer (score 0):

Do you know which fields/columns you want to keep, and what you'd like the "header" value to be ? , ie you want columns the first and third columns and you want them called "first" and "third" ? If so, you could build a `HashMap` of string/objects (or other appropriate type, depends on your actual data and needs), and add the `HashMap` to an `ArrayList` - this should get you going, just be sure to change the `HashMap` types as needed

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> arr=new ArrayList<>();
HashMap<String,String> hm=new HashMap<>();

while ((row = csvParser.nextRow()) != null) {
    if ((linecounter % 3) > 0 ) {
        // System.out.println("Read line: " + row);
        //System.out.println("First column of line: " + row.getField(0));

        // keep col1 and col3 
        hm.clear();
        hm.put("first",row.getField(0));
        hm.put("third",row.getField(2));
        arr.add(hm);
    }
    linecounter ++;
}
```

If you want to capture all columns, you can use a similar technique but I'd build a mapping data structure so that you can match field indexes to column header names in a loop to add each column to the `HashMap` that is then stored in the `ArrayList`

Comment: Yes, there just 2 fields that I actually need. I don't actually have a class that is dedicated to the data so I assume I'd be better of creating a class for each line of data (object) and building the hashmap of that object, then simply creating functions within the class which would return previously mentioned fields? Greatly appreciate your advice. Thank you.

Comment: A data class isn't needed, unless there need to be methods to transform that data for output or calculations. For something like an ETL process I'd skip having a class and just keep it in the ArrayList of HMs.

Comment: The data will actually be used for some calculations. I will be implementing functions later on which will use the data, hence I needed to figure out a way of adding the headers so I could extract fields such as Job ID.